# Osslsigncode can't locate openssl on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, signtool

I'm trying to install osslsigncode on a Windows 10 machine. I've installed OpenSSL, and when I run OpenSSL from MinGW I get

```
      OpenSSL>
```

And I can run genrsa, etc.

But when I run ./configure for osslsigncode, I get this error:

```
     checking sys/mman.h usability... no
     checking sys/mman.h presence... no
     checking for sys/mman.h... no
     checking windows.h usability... yes
     checking windows.h presence... yes
     checking for windows.h... yes
     checking for dlopen in -ldl... no
     checking termios.h usability... no
     checking termios.h presence... no
     checking for termios.h... no
     checking for getpass... no
     checking for GSF... no
     checking for OPENSSL... no
     checking for OPENSSL... no
     checking for RSA_verify in -lcrypto... no
     configure: error: OpenSSL 0.9.8 or later is required. http://www.openssl.org/
```

If I check for the version of OpenSSL,

```
    OpenSSL> version
    OpenSSL 1.0.0 29 Mar 2010
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I believe you need to install `openssl-dev` or `openssl-devel` for the headers rather than just the binaries.

Comment: Even for windows? I'm rather new to this

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set the global systemvariable `OPENSSL`.
This variable is requested in the file `configure.ac` and there in the two blocks named `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` are still more requirements that are checked during the configure-process.
You can set the variable `OPENSSL` statically, or for installation you do it like this:

```
  SET OPENSSL=/PATH/TO/OPENSSL/
  ./configure
  make
  make install
```

/PATH/TO/OPENSSL/ has to be replaced by the right existing path.
I don't know if a path for `OPENSSL` is enough or if you have to assign the path to a binary / extecutable file, you've to try it if you never get a better hint.